# Sender address rejected

Tags: php, email

I get this message when I try to send mail from php with my ISP SMTP:

```
Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 504 <bob>: Sender address rejected: need fully-qualified address in B:\testmail.php on line 2
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to specify `bob@domain.com` in your code.